# Conditional plotting for a subset of $\R^2$

Tags: pgfplots

Say I want to shade the following area:

```
$\{ (x, y) | 1-x y>0 \}$
```

As long as I specify the `x` and `y` boundaries, is there a tool I can use to achieve that result? That would suit me better than plotting the function and deciding which areas to shade.

Comment: In principle it is possible with pgfplots. However, unless you rely on `gnuplot` the result won't be as nice as plotting the function and deciding which side you want to shade.

Answer (score 1):

You can do implicit plots. Here are two examples, which get compared to explicit plots. I kept the number of samples low to show that for the same number of samples the implicit plots typically are not as compelling as those obtained with "plotting the function and deciding which side you want to shade".

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfplotsset{domain=0:5,ymax=5,xmax=5}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=implicit]
  \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
      x filter/.expression={1-x*y>0 ? x :nan}]
      \addplot3 [surf,shader=flat] {1};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[yshift=-6.5cm,view={0}{90},
    colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) color=(blue)}]
   \addplot3 [contour filled={levels={0}}] {1-x*y};
  \end{axis}
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=explicit]
  \begin{axis}[xshift=8cm]
   \addplot[blue,fill=blue] {1/x} |- (0,0) |- cycle;
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[xshift=8cm,yshift=-6.5cm]
   \addplot[blue,fill=blue,smooth] {1/x} |- (0,0) |- cycle;
  \end{axis}
 \end{scope} 
 \path (implicit.north) node[above] {implicit plots}
 (explicit.north) node[above] {explicit plots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't `\closedcycle` more `pgfplots`-like than `cycle` ?

Comment: @BambOo Maybe. I just chose something that works.

Comment: That sure is the first and foremost thing to seek ! :)